# Scrapy - Submit form with multiple buttons

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, forms, scrapy

I'm starting to work with scrapy and I managed to crawl through a series of forms, but the last form has two buttons, reject and accept.

```
<input name="_eventId_AttributeReleaseRejected" style="margin-right: 30px;" type="submit" value="Reject"> 
<input name="_eventId_proceed" type="submit" value="Accept">
```

How do I tell scrapy to choose Accept ?
I used this code

```
def thirdForm(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response, 
        formname="Form",
        callback=self.parseResponse)
```

but it chooses reject by default, How can I get past this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out how to do it, you can specify which button to submit using a property called `clickdata`
It's a python dictionary containing the name and/or the value of the button you want to submit.

Here's the code after editing

```
def thirdForm(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, 
            formname="Form",
            clickdata={"name":"_eventId_proceed", 'value' :'Accept'},
            callback=self.parseResponse)
```